# Is it good practice to store a file on the server, running a shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app running on a server 
to preprocess the data i am using system unix tools like so:

```
for (file in 1:length(files)){
    foon <- paste("data/",files[file],".txt",sep="")        
if(.Platform$OS.type == "unix") {
        system(paste("sed 's/\t/,/g' ", foon," | tail -n +2 > file",file, ".txt"))  
        }
       else {
        shell(paste("sed 's/\t/,/g' ", foon," | tail -n +2 > file",file,".txt", sep=""))  
      }
```

can this cause issues that i am not thinking about?
i am running the app on a Ubuntu 14  server

Comment: Don't get the `if` statement. If your app is running on an Ubuntu server and you know it, what's the point of checking the `OS.type`?

Comment: @nicola locally i am working on a windows machine, and so i dont have to have 2 different codes i do it that way

Comment: I'm still confused. If that code is part of `server.R`, then those commands are performed by the server (the PC hosting the app) and not by the client (the PC which is connecting to the app). With locally, are you meaning that you are developing your app on a Windows machine and then you'll transfer it on an Ubuntu server? Or you are just connecting with a Windows PC? In the second case the `if` condition is useless. However, I think that it is not good practice to use OS commands. I'm not familiar with `sed`, but if you explain what you want to do, surely there will be an R way to do it.

Comment: 1.  I am developing on a windows machine and then pushing via github to the server.
2. I am sure that there is a way to do it with R, but there are tasks that R is not good at like preprocessing data, that is why i want to know why is this not good practice

Comment: R totally rocks at processing data and could do that tab to comma conversion really easily and quickly.

Comment: I guess most would strongly disagree on "R is not good at preprocessing data", but that's not the point. The answer to your question is "it depends" on a whole lot of factors that you didn't specify. Are you going to distribute your code? If so, it's _very_ bad practice, since not each PC will have `sed` installed. Is your code tied with a machine? In that case, it can be ok, but you must be sure that `sed` won't be erased by the system administrator. Plus, it will be hardly portable if the need arises. There are a lot of stuff to be considered.

Comment: And of course +1000 to what @hrbrmstr said. In my experience when someone says "language is not good for task" is wrong and " I'm not good at task with language" is very often the truth.

Comment: @nicola i agree i will rephrase it easier for ME to preprocess with unix tools and it is not planned to be distributed thanks a lot for your answers

Comment: copied from the R manual 
    'There is a clear presumption by the designers of R that you will be able to modify your input files using other tools, such as file   editors or Perl to fit in with the requirements of R.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's your own server that you own and you're running Shiny Server on it, then it's absolutely fine to have files on it.  If you were running your app on shinyapps.io then it wouldn't be a good idea because it doesn't (yet) have persistent file storage, but on your own server you can access files is any way you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

I typically first put the files on tmp. This would be in the case where user inputs files from the shiny app. This is because from a web application, most often, a user may not have read/write access to anything other than /tmp. This also helps recalculation and dynamic processing to work without having to reload user input files. To do this, you could simply do a file.copy to tmpdir on ubuntu.

I did encounter situations where these saved files would then get cached. To handle this, I would have a "Refresh" button in the app which when clicked would delete all the saved files on tmpdir.

If on the other hand these are files you would need statically for processing in the application (like a meta file or some reference fixed data for instance), then you could put the files in the same directory as the app code files.